# Can a Chrome browser window detect if I am using software like Anydesk?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, anydesk

I use Chrome to work online. I want to demonstrate my work to my friend using Anydesk. Can Chrome or installed 'Work extension' on Chrome detect if the content on the tab is being captured by Anydesk?